# Azure Load Balancer (Resource Manager) - How to use public IP for backend pool

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-virtual-network

I can't for the life of me find documentation or a clear way to assign the public IP of a VM to the backend pool for a load-balancer (both VM and loadbalancer are Resource Manager assets).

I'm starting to hit the SNAT-related ephemeral port allocation limits with the backend pool of the loadbalancer, and need to use the public ip for a given vm -- though the only information I'm able to find is regarding assigning instance level public ip addresses under the classic deployment model.

Can anyone offer any insights around this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how would you benefit from that?
I'm sure you cannot achieve that, since you basically attach a NIC to a backend pool of a Load Balance (there's the `loadBalancerBackendAddressPools` property on the VM NIC).

Also, if you look at the Load Balancer reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network/loadbalancers) you will find that the backend pool is a  `Collection of references to IPs defined in network interfaces`. And those are basically the ips in the network interface definition. not public ips.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that definitely helped clear up the confusion.  I was carrying over the guidance for VMs under the Classic deployment model, which indicated that instance level public ips needed to be used to overcome the SNAT-related ephemeral port allocation restrictions.

Comment: btw, you can use application gateway for that @feral_frolicker https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq